# How to do calculations on fields Focus change in Koltin

Tags: android, kotlin

Good Morning brothers. I am working on an android form in Koltin which will save the data into MySQL. The problem I am facing is how can I save calculated data to an EditText field while entering data. I tried to add the calculation in oCreate instance but the intent crashes cause there is null point Exception as the form created is empty values. My code is appended below. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

I am trying to calculate value of project cost * ITRation / 100 and set the value to editTextITAMount but I am unable to do so.

```
class ProjectActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //edittext and spinner
    private var editTextProjectName: EditText? = null
    private var spinnerProjectType: Spinner? = null
    private var editTextDepartment: EditText? = null
    private var editTextDateAwarded: EditText? = null
    private var editTextProjectLocation: EditText? = null
    private var editTextProjectCity: EditText? = null
    private var editTextProjectDistrict: EditText? = null
    private var spinnerJointVenture: Spinner? = null
    private var editTextJointVentureCoy: EditText? = null
    private var spinnerProjectStatus: Spinner? = null
    private var editTextProjectCost: EditText? = null
    private var spinnerITRatio: Spinner? = null
    private var editTextITAmount: EditText? = null
    private var spinnerGSTBST: Spinner? = null
    private var editTextGSTBSTAmount: EditText? = null






    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_project)

        //getting it from xml
        editTextProjectName = findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectName) as EditText
        spinnerProjectType = findViewById(R.id.spinnerProjectType) as Spinner
        editTextDepartment = findViewById(R.id.editTextDepartment) as EditText
        val mPickTimeBtn = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)
        editTextDateAwarded = findViewById(R.id.editTextDateAwarded) as EditText
        editTextProjectLocation = findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectLocation) as EditText
        editTextProjectCity = findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectCity) as EditText
        editTextProjectDistrict = findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectDistrict) as EditText
        spinnerJointVenture = findViewById(R.id.spinnerJointVenture) as Spinner
        editTextJointVentureCoy = findViewById(R.id.editTextJointVentureCoy) as EditText
        spinnerProjectStatus = findViewById(R.id.spinnerProjectStatus) as Spinner
        editTextProjectCost = findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectCost) as EditText
        spinnerITRatio = findViewById(R.id.spinnerITRatio) as Spinner
        editTextITAmount = findViewById(R.id.editTextITAmount) as EditText
        spinnerGSTBST = findViewById(R.id.spinnerGSTBST) as Spinner
        editTextGSTBSTAmount = findViewById(R.id.editTextGSBSTAmount) as EditText



        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        mPickTimeBtn.setOnClickListener {

            val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                // Display Selected date in TextView
                editTextDateAwarded!!.setText("" + dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year)
            }, year, month, day)
            dpd.show()

        }
        //adding a click listener to button
        this.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonAddProject).setOnClickListener { addProject() }

        //in the second button click
        //opening the activity to display all the artist
        //it will give error as we dont have this activity so remove this part for now to run the app
    }

    private fun calculation() {

    }

    //adding a new record to database
    private fun addProject() {
        //getting the record values
        val projectName = editTextProjectName?.text.toString()
        val projectType = spinnerProjectType?.selectedItem.toString()
        val department = editTextDepartment?.text.toString()
        val dateAwarded = editTextDateAwarded?.text.toString()
        val projectLocation = editTextProjectLocation?.text.toString()
        val projectCity = editTextProjectCity?.text.toString()
        val projectDistrict = editTextProjectDistrict?.text.toString()
        val jointVenture = spinnerJointVenture?.selectedItem.toString()
        val jointVentureWith = editTextJointVentureCoy?.text.toString()
        val projectStatus = spinnerProjectStatus?.selectedItem.toString()
        val projectCost= editTextProjectCost?.text.toString()
        val ITRatio = spinnerITRatio?.selectedItem.toString()
        val ITAmount= editTextITAmount?.text.toString()
        val GSTBST = spinnerGSTBST?.selectedItem.toString()
        val GSTBSTAmount= editTextGSTBSTAmount?.text.toString()

        val a: Int = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editTextProjectCost).getText().toString().toInt()
        val b: Int = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinnerITRatio).getSelectedItem().toString().toInt()


        val multiplication = a * b / 100
        editTextITAmount!!.setText("" + multiplication)
        //creating volley string request
        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, EndPoints.URL_ADD_PROJECT,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                try {
                    val obj = JSONObject(response)
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, ProjectsViewActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            },
            object : Response.ErrorListener {
                override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }
            }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("projectName", projectName)
                params.put("projectType", projectType)
                params.put("department", department)
                params.put("dateAwarded", dateAwarded)
                params.put("projectLocation", projectLocation)
                params.put("projectCity", projectCity)
                params.put("projectDistrict", projectDistrict)
                params.put("jointVenture", jointVenture)
                params.put("jointVentureWith", jointVentureWith)
                params.put("projectStatus", projectStatus)
                params.put("projectCost", projectCost)
                params.put("ITRatio", ITRatio)
                params.put("ITAmount", ITAmount)
                params.put("GSTBST", GSTBST)
                params.put("GSTBSTAmount", GSTBSTAmount)
                return params
            }
        }

        //adding request to queue
        VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: please give a full stacktrace and code with imports?